# One Solr core, multiple unrelated tables

Tags: java-8, solr5

I need to search over multiple tables, getting only one resultset, but these tables don't have any relationship.

Can I do it with Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Solr's aliases might fit your needs.

Create your alias with :

http://[solr.host:port]/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=testalias&collections=[collection1],[collection2]

and then query as usual as if "testalias" was one collection. For example:
http://[solr.host:port]/solr/testalias/select?q=*:*&rows=100&wt=json&indent=true

This query will return all the data from both collections.